# Latex incorporate a fraction in tan

Tags: fractions

I want to write in latex that an angle equals to tan of (BM/AB).
I wrote this:

```
$\widehat{BAM}$ = $ \tan ($ \dfrac {BM} {AB} $)$
```

But I have an error "missing $ inserted. Can someone help me?

Comment: Shouldn't “tan” go to the other side?

Answer (score 6):

You only need to use the `$` math mode delimiters at the start and end of the formula; no point (or use) inserting more of them inside the formula.

I would also like to suggest two more modifications aimed at improving the typographic result:

1. Don't use parentheses around the fraction term -- the parentheses add nothing in terms of clarity for this simple expression.
2. Encase `BAM` in a `\textit` instruction to typeset this string a bit more compactly. (By default, while in math mode LaTeX will treat "BAM" as if it were the product of the three variables B, A, and M, leading to rather wide spacing of the overall expression.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \dfrac macro  
\begin{document} 
$\widehat{\textit{BAM}} = \tan \dfrac{BM}{AB}$
\end{document}
```

Addendum: If this is an inline (as opposed to display-style) formula, you probably shouldn't use `\dfrac`; use either `\frac` or use a "slash" division bar (and now *with* parentheses). With either adjustment, you'll get a much more even-looking paragraph.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} 
$\widehat{\textit{BAM}} = \tan \frac{BM}{AB}$

$\widehat{\textit{BAM}} = \tan (BM/AB)$
\end{document}
```

---

Finally, as @egreg has pointed out in a comment, the *math* represented by your expression really needs to be fixed as well. Depending on what `AB` and `BM` actually are, the *ratio* of these two entities *is* the tangent of some angle (or a sine, a cosine, or maybe something else altogether); no need to take the tangent of the ratio, right? Or, if `\widehat{BAM}` is supposed to be an angle, should you possibly be writing `\widehat{BAM}=\arctan \frac{BM}{AB}`?

Comment: Of course the math is wrong. The tangent of the angle is the ratio of the two segments, not conversely.

Comment: @egreg - Indeed. I've added a note to this effect.

Answer (score 3):

*Note: this answer address the immediate issue of using just one pair of math delimiters, but doesn't address the fact that `\dfrac` versus `\frac` (as [egreg noted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160491/latex-incorporate-a-fraction-in-tan#comment366847_160493) in the comments).  [Miko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160506/29288) addresses the main issue, as well as a number of others.*

You don't need all those dollar signs.  You just need to enter math mode once, and to leave it once.  You also probably want to use `\left(` and `\right)` to make the parenthesis big enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\widehat{BAM} = \tan \left(\dfrac {BM}{AB}\right)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using `\dfrac` in inline mode spoils the uniformity of the leading. The parentheses are useless.

Comment: @egreg Good point!  I answered this quickly before it got migrated from Stack Overflow, and was only addressing the immediate issue of the dollar signs.  [Mico's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160506/29288) handles this correctly, as well as a number of other issues, and I'll add a note to my answer as such.

Answer (score 0):

You only need `$$` on both ends. Change it to:

```
$ \widehat{BAM} = \tan (\dfrac {BM} {AB}) $
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful with commands intended to be used in math mode (`\dfrac` as well). So, in this case you can use one of the above propositions or, if you would like, just write the following:

> $\widehat{BAM}$ = $ \tan ($ $\dfrac {BM} {AB}$ $)$

But this is a very bad style if for no other reason than because you may forget a space between both $.

Also remember that parentheses as command part should be also placed within `$...$`.

Comment: It's not only bad style: it's simply wrong. It's a unique formula and so it should go entirely between `$` symbols; using `\dfrac` in inline mode is not recommended. Why not the simpler `$\widehat{BAM}=\tan\frac{BM}{AB}$`? The parentheses are not required.